# Window 7: Inactive restore button. why?

Tags: windows-7, window, system-restore

[image: rst]

Window 7 has the restore points available, but the restore button is inactive. what could be the reason and whats the fix?

Comment: Does it activate for other restore points? Have you checked the restore points to see if they're successfully created? Have you checked the event logs?

Comment: You might run vssadmin list shadows command to see if the corresponding shadow copy is existing.

Comment: No it is not restoring any file/folder although instances or restoration points are available+ it also creates new instances. The issue is in that button, which is inactive.

Comment: What happens if you select one and hit Open button

Comment: It opens old date files.